# Flutter | ExpansionTile property "children" throws a Bottom Overflowed issue on expanding

Tags: listview, widget, flutter, expansion

I am building a list of items fetched from Firestore wrapped in an `ExpansionTile` inside a `ListView.builder()`. The data is fetched properly. No issues there. I can see the list of those items.

The problem is on Tile expansion I need to display some `ListTile`. But on expansion, it throws me a `Bottom Overflowed by X pixels`.

To tackle this, I tried wrapping it in a `ListView` but it throws exception -

> Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The
>   method '<=' was called on null.

No luck.

I am coding something like this -

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewExpansionPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewExpansionPanelState createState() => _NewExpansionPanelState();
}

class _NewExpansionPanelState extends State<NewExpansionPanel> {
  Widget getListOfTexts(){
    return ListView(
      children: <Text>[
        Text('one'),
        Text('two'),
        Text('three'),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection(*someCollection*).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading.....");

        return ListView.builder(
          itemExtent: 80.0,
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return new ExpansionTile(
              children: [
                getListOfTexts()
              ],
              title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    document['something'] ?? ' ',
                  ),
                  Text(document['title'] ?? '<No title retrieved>'),
                ],
              ), 
              onExpansionChanged: (bool isExpanded) {
                // put some code here in future
              },
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing. I just had to remove `itemExtent: 80.0` property on the `ListView.builder`. This was causing the `Bottom Overflowed` Issue.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm hitting this problem in the reverse order.  I had a BIG list and itemExtent fixed my laggy scrolling, but then I got the same issue you saw.  So my question is how to use both?!  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try using the ExpansionTile children Texts directly without ListView?
It's like this...

```
       ...//      
    return new ExpansionTile(
          children: [
            Text('one'),
            Text('two'),
            Text('three'),
          ],
        ...
```

or Use ListTile for the texts..

```
return new ExpansionTile(
                children: [
                  ListTile(title: Text('one'),),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Two'),),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Three'),),           
                 ],
```

Comment: Yes. Thats what I was using but this causes the `Bottom Overflowed by X pixels`. In order to tackle this issue, I added the `ListView`.